# K-d Tree Level Order Traversal

Tags: java, data-structures, kdtree

Is there any way for us to exploit the characteristic of a k-d tree to print it out in a level order (top row to bottom row, left to right)?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show your work so that people can help you.

Comment: It's just a conceptual question. I've not written any code yet. I'm thinking of writing them only if it works conceptually. Does this make sense?

Comment: No! Unfortunately, it does not make much sense to me. But, you can check the `points()` method from [this GitHub repository code](https://github.com/BLuEScioN/Kd-Trees/blob/65475295a9ba5918f6ffb4c24bea2272d3d149e4/KdTreeST.java#L167) to understand how you can solve the KD-tree level-order traversal.